# Adding a condition to context in Navigator.push

Tags: flutter, dart

Per to my knowledge when we use `Navigator.push()` we have to provide the context which is the screen or rout we are currently in usually then we provide the redirecting to new rout.

Am trying to set a conditional statement that states "if we are in the Otp Screen don't change the rout otherwise go to the Otp Screen".

```
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => OtpScreen(verificationId: verificationId),
      ),
    );
```

using the Navigator how to achieve an approach that checks what current rout you are in and set a condition as I mentioned above. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,

```
if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name == '/otp') {
  
} else {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => OtpScreen(verificationId: verificationId),
      settings: RouteSettings(name: '/otp'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: in '/otp' do you mean the file path ? like 'otp_screen.dart'?